# Apache error after renewing SSL certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration

A couple of days ago I tried to renew my ssl certificate. From my provider I got the usual private key, intermediate and public key. So I went ahead and exchanged the files on my server. But ever since I did that the website hasn't been working anymore. In Chrome I always get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".
So I enabled ssl debugging for apache in my vhost config. I found the following error in the logs but couldn't figure out how to solve this:

```
AH00566: request failed: malformed request line
```

Has anyone seen that error before? I already googled but couldn't find any helpful information.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andreas